# For String Input : "" exception

Tags: java, service, wsdl, weblogic, ioexception

I have weird exception about connector codes on java with soap service ,

I have generated source code due to wsdl and I put that to my project but I couldn't worked properly , I got belove exception  but the weird thing is I cropped that wsdl source code and make a new project which just exist that source , and it worked , I couldn't find a way, 
wait your reply

---

> > FATAL [ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '11' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)' - 29.08.2013 17:32:41,602 Thu EEST
> >     javax.servlet.ServletException: javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: java.io.IOException: For input string: ""

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: java.io.IOException: For input string: ""
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:420)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:537)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:699)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:844)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:242)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:216)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:132)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:338)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.TailFilter.doFilter(TailFilter.java:25)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:74)
    at com.netas.vas.tic.ws.aop.LoggingFilter.doFilter(LoggingFilter.java:49)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:74)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.wrapRun(WebAppServletContext.java:3288)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run(WebAppServletContext.java:3254)
    at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
    at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:120)
    at weblogic.servlet.provider.WlsSubjectHandle.run(WlsSubjectHandle.java:57)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.doSecuredExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2163)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.securedExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2089)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:2074)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1513)
    at weblogic.servlet.provider.ContainerSupportProviderImpl$WlsRequestExecutor.run(ContainerSupportProviderImpl.java:254)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:256)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:221)
Caused by: javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: java.io.IOException: For input string: ""
    at com.sun.xml.ws.streaming.TidyXMLStreamReader.close(TidyXMLStreamReader.java:73)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.wsdl.parser.RuntimeWSDLParser.parseWSDL(RuntimeWSDLParser.java:421)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.wsdl.parser.RuntimeWSDLParser.parse(RuntimeWSDLParser.java:184)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.wsdl.parser.RuntimeWSDLParser.parse(RuntimeWSDLParser.java:154)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.wsdl.parser.RuntimeWSDLParser.parse(RuntimeWSDLParser.java:139)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.parseWSDL(WSServiceDelegate.java:287)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.<init>(WSServiceDelegate.java:249)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.<init>(WSServiceDelegate.java:200)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.<init>(WSServiceDelegate.java:190)
    at weblogic.wsee.jaxws.spi.WLSServiceDelegate.<init>(WLSServiceDelegate.java:89)
    at weblogic.wsee.jaxws.spi.WLSProvider$ServiceDelegateImpl.<init>(WLSProvider.java:674)
    at weblogic.wsee.jaxws.spi.WLSProvider.createServiceDelegate(WLSProvider.java:141)
    at weblogic.wsee.jaxws.spi.WLSProvider.createServiceDelegate(WLSProvider.java:114)
    at javax.xml.ws.Service.<init>(Service.java:92)
    at com.netas.vas.tic.ws.client.freeurl.subscription.SOF99SubscriptionCreateRequestWithControl_Service.<init>(SOF99SubscriptionCreateRequestWithControl_Service.java:45)
    at com.netas.vas.tic.ws.rest.RegisterResource.freeUrl(RegisterResource.java:390)
    at com.netas.vas.tic.ws.rest.RegisterResource.newPerson(RegisterResource.java:214)
    at com.netas.vas.tic.ws.rest.RegisterResource.register(RegisterResource.java:139)
    at com.netas.vas.tic.ws.rest.RegisterResource_msujha_NoIntfViewImpl.__WL_invoke(Unknown Source)
    at weblogic.ejb.container.internal.SessionLocalMethodInvoker.invoke(SessionLocalMethodInvoker.java:31)
    at com.netas.vas.tic.ws.rest.RegisterResource_msujha_NoIntfViewImpl.register(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at weblogic.jaxrs.dispatch.EJBDispatchProvider$EJBMethodInvoker.invoke(EJBDispatchProvider.java:58)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider$ResponseOutInvoker._dispatch(AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider.java:205)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.dispatch(ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.java:75)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.HttpMethodRule.accept(HttpMethodRule.java:288)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.ResourceClassRule.accept(ResourceClassRule.java:108)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RootResourceClassesRule.accept(RootResourceClassesRule.java:84)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1469)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1400)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1349)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1339)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:416)
    ... 23 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: For input string: ""
    at weblogic.utils.http.HttpChunkInputStream.initChunk(HttpChunkInputStream.java:69)
    at weblogic.utils.http.HttpChunkInputStream.skip(HttpChunkInputStream.java:215)
    at weblogic.utils.http.HttpChunkInputStream.skipAllChunk(HttpChunkInputStream.java:395)
    at weblogic.utils.http.HttpChunkInputStream.close(HttpChunkInputStream.java:291)
    at weblogic.net.http.KeepAliveStream.close(KeepAliveStream.java:122)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.streaming.TidyXMLStreamReader.close(TidyXMLStreamReader.java:71)
    ... 59 more
```

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Comment: Please provide relevant source code, testing method, and test cases.

Comment: why 5 people sent negative vote to me , okey I will add

Comment: If *you* have not been able to find out the problem with all the information I'm sure you have, how do you expect we can?  The alternatives are:  1)  A person who happened to see your question also happened to experience exactly the same symptoms by the same reasons (rare, as the post has had just 45 views)  2)  We are thousands, millions of times smarter than you (and this is even more difficult than the previous).  So?  **We need more information**

Answer (score 0):

I added my service class

```
package freeurl.subscription;

import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import javax.xml.namespace.QName;
import javax.xml.ws.WebEndpoint;
import javax.xml.ws.WebServiceClient;
import javax.xml.ws.WebServiceFeature;
import javax.xml.ws.Service;

/**
 * This class was generated by Apache CXF 2.7.5
 * 2013-06-11T16:22:49.956+03:00
 * Generated source version: 2.7.5
 * 
 */
@WebServiceClient(name = "SO_F99_SubscriptionCreateRequestWithControl", 
                  wsdlLocation = "http:/bla.bla:9700/orabpel/default/SO_F99_SubscriptionCreateRequestWithControl/2.2?wsdl",
                  targetNamespace = "http://www.accenture.com/assets/sdp/sync/SO_F99_SubscriptionCreateRequestWithControl") 
public class SOF99SubscriptionCreateRequestWithControl_Service extends Service {

    public final static URL WSDL_LOCATION;`enter code here`

    public final static QName SERVICE = new QName("http://www.accenture.com/assets/sdp/sync/SO_F99_SubscriptionCreateRequestWithControl", "SO_F99_SubscriptionCreateRequestWithControl");
    public final static QName SOF99SubscriptionCreateRequestWithControlPort = new QName("http://www.accenture.com/assets/sdp/sync/SO_F99_SubscriptionCreateRequestWithControl", "SO_F99_SubscriptionCreateRequestWithControlPort");
    static {
        URL url = null;
        try {
            url = new URL("http://bla.bla:9700/orabpel/default/SO_F99_SubscriptionCreateRequestWithControl/2.2");
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(SOF99SubscriptionCreateRequestWithControl_Service.class.getName())
                .log(java.util.logging.Level.INFO, 
                     "Can not initialize the default wsdl from {0}", "http://10.201.148.51:9700/orabpel/default/SO_F99_SubscriptionCreateRequestWithControl/SO_F99_SubscriptionCreateRequestWithControl?wsdl");
        }
        WSDL_LOCATION = url;
    }

    public SOF99SubscriptionCreateRequestWithControl_Service(URL wsdlLocation) {
        super(wsdlLocation, SERVICE);
    }

    public SOF99SubscriptionCreateRequestWithControl_Service(URL wsdlLocation, QName serviceName) {
        super(wsdlLocation, serviceName);
    }

    public SOF99SubscriptionCreateRequestWithControl_Service() {
        super(WSDL_LOCATION, SERVICE);
    }


    /**
     *
     * @return
     *     returns SOF99SubscriptionCreateRequestWithControl
     */
    @WebEndpoint(name = "SO_F99_SubscriptionCreateRequestWithControlPort")
    public SOF99SubscriptionCreateRequestWithControl getSOF99SubscriptionCreateRequestWithControlPort() {
        return super.getPort(SOF99SubscriptionCreateRequestWithControlPort, SOF99SubscriptionCreateRequestWithControl.class);
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @param features
     *     A list of {@link javax.xml.ws.WebServiceFeature} to configure on the proxy.  Supported features not in the <code>features</code> parameter will have their default values.
     * @return
     *     returns SOF99SubscriptionCreateRequestWithControl
     */
    @WebEndpoint(name = "SO_F99_SubscriptionCreateRequestWithControlPort")
    public SOF99SubscriptionCreateRequestWithControl getSOF99SubscriptionCreateRequestWithControlPort(WebServiceFeature... features) {
        return super.getPort(SOF99SubscriptionCreateRequestWithControlPort, SOF99SubscriptionCreateRequestWithControl.class, features);
    }

}
```

and I called from here that service

```
public TSOresult freeUrl(Msisdn msisdn) {
        QName SERVICE_NAME = new QName("http://www.accenture.com/assets/sdp/sync/SO_F99_SubscriptionCreateRequestWithControl", "SO_F99_SubscriptionCreateRequestWithControl");
        // URL wsdlURL = SOF99SubscriptionCreateRequestWithControl_Service.WSDL_LOCATION;
        VasLogger.logInfo("Free URL WSDL " + FreeUrlConfig.getFreeUrlWsdl() + " with msisdn " + msisdn.asUsername());
        URL wsdlURL = null;
        try {
            wsdlURL = new URL(FreeUrlConfig.getFreeUrlWsdl());
        } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {
            VasLogger.logError("Free url error: " + FreeUrlConfig.getFreeUrlWsdl() + " " + wsdlURL.toString(), ex);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            VasLogger.logError("Free url error: " + FreeUrlConfig.getFreeUrlWsdl() + " " + wsdlURL.toString(), e);
        }


        SOF99SubscriptionCreateRequestWithControl_Service ss = new SOF99SubscriptionCreateRequestWithControl_Service(wsdlURL, SERVICE_NAME);
        SOF99SubscriptionCreateRequestWithControl port = ss.getSOF99SubscriptionCreateRequestWithControlPort();
        ObjectFactory objectFactory = new ObjectFactory();


        com.netas.vas.tic.ws.client.freeurl.subscription.TSODATA _process_payloadVal = objectFactory.createTSODATA();

        javax.xml.ws.Holder<com.netas.vas.tic.ws.client.freeurl.subscription.TSODATA> _process_payload = new javax.xml.ws.Holder<com.netas.vas.tic.ws.client.freeurl.subscription.TSODATA>(_process_payloadVal);
        TSOheader header = objectFactory.createTSOheader();
        String transactionIdStr = "848" + CodeGenerator.generateCode(16, CodeType.NUMERIC); //transactionId();

        header.setMSISDN(msisdn.asUsername());
        header.setOrderId(transactionIdStr);
        TSOattributes attributes = objectFactory.createTSOattributes();
        List<Attribute> attributeList = attributes.getAttribute();

        Attribute channel = new Attribute();
        channel.setName("CHANNEL");
        channel.setValue("VAS Server");

        Attribute userId = new Attribute();
        userId.setName("USER_ID");
        userId.setValue(FreeUrlConfig.getUserId());

        Attribute application = new Attribute();
        application.setName("APPLICATION");
        application.setValue(FreeUrlConfig.getApplication());

        Attribute transactionId = new Attribute();
        transactionId.setName("TRANSACTION_ID");
        transactionId.setValue(transactionIdStr);

        Attribute catalogOfferId = new Attribute();
        catalogOfferId.setName("CATALOG_OFFER_ID");
        catalogOfferId.setValue(FreeUrlConfig.getOfferId());

        Attribute campaignId = new Attribute();
        campaignId.setName("CAMPAIGN_ID");
        campaignId.setValue(FreeUrlConfig.getCampaignId());

        Attribute msisdnAttr = new Attribute();
        msisdnAttr.setName("MSISDN");
        msisdnAttr.setValue(msisdn.asUsername());

        Attribute callPermissionFlowFlag = new Attribute();
        callPermissionFlowFlag.setName("CALL_PERMISSION_FLOW_FLAG");
        callPermissionFlowFlag.setValue(FreeUrlConfig.isCallPermissionFlowFlagActive() ? "Y" : "N");


        attributeList.add(channel);
        attributeList.add(userId);
        attributeList.add(application);
        attributeList.add(transactionId);
        attributeList.add(catalogOfferId);
        attributeList.add(campaignId);
        attributeList.add(msisdnAttr);
        attributeList.add(callPermissionFlowFlag);


        _process_payloadVal.setTSOheader(header);
        _process_payloadVal.setTSOattributes(attributes);
        port.process(_process_payload);

        VasLogger.logInfo("FREE URL PROCESS PAYLOAD: " + _process_payload.toString() + " ATTRIBUTES " + attributes);

        return _process_payload.value.getTSOresult();
    }
```